# Could not find Developer Disk Image iOS 10

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios10

I have updated my iOS device to iOS 10, now Xcode says "Could not find Developer Disk Image" while trying to run on iPhone using Xcode 7.3.1
How can I fix the problem and make Xcode support iOS 10 devices?

Comment: Xcode 8 is what you need for developing on iOS10.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to develop with Xcode 7 on your iOS10 device :

1. Rename your Xcode.app to Xcode7.app and download Xcode 8 from the app store.
2. Run Xcode 8 once to install it.
3. Open the terminal and create a symbolic link from Xcode 8 Developer Disk Image 10.0 to Xcode 8 Developer Disk Image folder using this command:

**ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ (14A345)/ /Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0**

*Note : This works for Xcode 9 and above*

[Source](http://bsn.io/code/reference/2016/08/26/installing-on-ios-10-with-xcode-7/)

**UPDATE 2018:**
If you want to use Xcode 9 with iOS 12:

1. Download Xcode 10 (still in beta right now)
2. Put it in the Application folder as Xcode-beta.app
3. Open the terminal and use the command below:

**ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.0\ (16A5354b)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.0**

Comment: Copy the folder: `10.0 (14A345)` from path: `Xcode 8 -> Show Package Contents`, **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** and paste `10.0 (14A345)` folder inside the Xcode 7 path **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** and... works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Of course copy/past the `10.0 (14A345)` folder works as well but you will loose space and you won't get the last disk image from Xcode if it is updated.

Comment: This is the command that worked for me (change the Xcode.app names depending on how you renamed them - in my case, I have Xcode8.app for Xcode 8 and Xcode.app for Xcode 7.3.1): `ln -s /Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0\ \(14A345\) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

Comment: For xcode 8.2.1 and xcode 7.3.1 you can do this "ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.2\ \(14C89\)/ /Applications/Xcode7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/"

Answer (score 2):

As holex says installing [Xcode 8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You may try downloading a Developer Disk Image for the required iOS version, as of your mobile device; ***If you only want a quick and simple solution..***

You need to goto:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneO‌​S.platform/DeviceSup‌​port/
```

and paste the Developer Disk Image you just manually downloaded.