# Xcode not printing crash log on iOS real device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios10

Lastly I realize this issue using my real device in Xcode

If the app that I'm developing crashes, the crash log is not printed in Xcode but, if I run the same project in simulator and replicate the same crash the log is successfully printed.

If the app crashes using a **real device** this is printed:

After a crash it prints a single line:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Also I receive this log:

```
If the app crashes using a real device this is printed:
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

I'm using:

Xcode 7.3.1 with iOS 10 developers disk image see [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576363/could-not-find-developer-disk-image-ios-10).

Real device: iOS 10.0.2

Is there a way to solve this issue and see the crash information again using a real device in Xcode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced same issue, and resolved it by removing "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" - disable from scheme environment variables.